# jar dependency with provide not working

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, dependencies

I have a project in which i have to use a library (.jar files) in compile time only. The files should not be present in runtime. With this configuration it should work:

```
...app/libs/edm.jar
...app/libs/kcm.jar
...app/libs/rc.jar
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
...
    provided files('libs/edm.jar')
    provided files('libs/kcm.jar')
    provided files('libs/rc.jar')
...
}
```

But it isnt. The library is being compiled to runtime and i can't find a cause to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
providedCompile
```

instead of

```
provided
```

So your dependencies should look like this:

```
dependencies{
...
    providedCompile files('libs/edm.jar')
    providedCompile files('libs/kcm.jar')
    providedCompile files('libs/rc.jar')
...
}
```

Comment: gradle dsl method not found

Comment: Ok, so you do not have the plugin. Please check  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21238557/3231532) answer and do either one of the things suggested (the apply plugin way is quicker and better imho). Try again afterwards.

Comment: isn't 'provided' supposed to work like that? Available at compile but not runtime?